# Getting User Name and Password

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a login prompt. I have a xml file like this:

```
<Users>
 <User Name=User1 Password=Pass1/>
 <User Name=User2 Password=Pass2/>
</Users>
```

How to find if a UserName which is entered in a textbox exists in the file and find if the password is entered correctly? If there's a better way than using xml, can you provide any info?

Comment: In VB.Net Web and Windows codes are the same by default ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple places to peruse:

http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/10/27/create-a-login-window-in-wpf.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/7723452e-9128-4ed7-b0ad-db7a1e3b3af7/

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, but are you saying that you're storing the password as plain text in an XML file? This isn't a good practice. You should at least be encrytping the password.

If you insist on doing it this way, check out [LINQ To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx), which you could use to read the password from the correct user, and compare it to the one input.

With regards your question of doing this a better way, is this a desktop app or web app?

Answer (score 0):

This code is in VB 6 (only InStr function) but you can understand it or convert it to VB.Net if you have Artinsoft converter.
Try this (without any XML helpers):

```
Function CheckLoginPassword( UserName, Password)
   Dim l as string, allText as string
   l="<User Name=" & UserName & " Password=" & Password & "/>"
   '... HERE write code which will copy your XML's contents to variable allText
   If InStr(1,allText,l)>0 then 
       CheckLoginPassword=True
   Endif
End Function
```

After this you can write anywhere:

```
If CheckLogin (txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)=true then ... else ...
```